# Turning outbound links into a page with an iframe to display an ad?

Tags: iframe

So I'm working on this Directory site. We have a list of 20,000 businesses, and many of them have a link to their website.

The owner of the website asked me if we could change these links to point to a page that would embed the website in an iframe, with an ad on top (to make more ad revenues).

To me it sounds a bit shady, but besides breaking the back/forward navigation, I don't see any harm done.

Do you guys see any problem with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Think About your site users and your goal.

If your site is developed to give Directory Details For the Targeted Use ( your user) then linking to that revenue page is not a good approach, next time that user won't visit your site for that details.